# Excel formula to get everything after second decimal from a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following as a text. I used the following formula and it gives me everything after the first decimal. I need to get everything after the second decimal. I am trying get 5.1 or 5.10 or 5.12

=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)), the result is 7.5.1 and so forth

```
14.7.5.1
14.7.5.10
14.7.5.12
14.7.5.2
14.7.5.3
14.7.5.5
14.7.5.6
14.7.5.7
14.7.5.8
14.7.5.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `RIGHT`,`LEN`,`FIND`, and `SUBSTITUTE` to do this.

`=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","~",2)))`

Comment: Yes, `SUBSTITUTE` is a good choice since it allows you to specify which instance as the last argument.

Comment: This formula is good as well. Both Alexis Olson and BigBen formula works. I picked this one because Alexis recommends this over her solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way, but what occurs to me off the top of my head would be to just do what you've done twice. Find everything after the first period and then find everything after the first period in that string:

```
=RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)), LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))-FIND(".",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2))))
```

Comment: This formula is good as well. Both Alexis Olson and BigBen formula works. I picked the following because Alexis recommends this over her solution.

Comment: Thank you for jumping in fast and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option,

```
=REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND(".", A2, FIND(".", A2)+1), TEXT(,))
```